# Nested Json Structure modelling to NoSQL attribute

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I want to create a table in Dynamo DB with below structure.

```
{
 "id" : 123,
 "name" : "xyz",
 "info" : {
    "key1" : "val1",
    "key2": {
                "key3": [
                    "val3",
                ],
            }
    }
}
```

The simplest solution is

```
| id  | name | info          |
| 123 | xyz  | {json string} |
```

But what are some better solution, other than making the "key1"/"key2" as TOP-LEVEL attributes.
Please help, with a more optimal solution !